# Whether to use "entstanden" or "entstehend" for "ensuing"?

Tags: word-choice

> die **entstandene** Verwirrung nützen
>
> die **entstehende** Verwirrung nützen

In order to express the idea of "take advantage of the ensuing confusion", I'm split between Present Participle and Past Participle. I wonder if both can work or there is some distinction to be aware of?

Answer (score 4):

The distinction is the same in German as it is in English:

> take advantage of the ensuing confusion

Means confusion is currently developing (most probably still escalating) and someone takes advantage of it

This translates to present parciple - *seinen Vorteil aus der entstehenden Verwirrung ziehen*

> take advantage of the ensued confusion

Means confusion *was* ensuing (and is still present, but most probably not further developing) and someone takes advantage of it

This translates to past participle - *seinen Vorteil aus der entstandenen Verwirrung ziehen*

Comment: Hi. To talk about "the ensuing confusion" that is expected to take form in the future (not-currently-existing one), should I still use "entstehend"?

Comment: *ensuing* means to me something going on atm and some of its effect is already there. Like a *sinking* ship - you wouldn't say it's only "sunk in future"? Apart from that, if you really want to express some future events, you should really use the future tense - which is - strictly speaking, wrongly - very often replaced by present tense, both in English and in German.